# Retrieve data from file written in FORTRAN during program run

Tags: fortran

I am trying to write a series of values for time (real values) into a dat file in FORTRAN. This is a part of an MPI code and the code runs for a long time. So I would like to extract data at every time step and print it into a file and read the file any time during the execution of the program. Currently, the problem I am facing is, the values of time are not written into the file until the program ends. I have put the open statement before the do loop and the close statement after the end of do loop.

The parts of my code look like:

```
open(unit=57,file='inst.dat')
do loop starts
.
.
.
write(57,*) time
.
.
.
end do
close(57)
```

Comment: How do you look at the contents of the file while it is running?

Comment: Instead of open, write, close, open, read..., you could do open, write, rewind, read.

Comment: suspect he wants to monitor progress by looking at the file externally.

Answer (score 0):

try `call flush(unit)`.  Check your compiler docs as this is i think an extension.

You mention MPI: For parallel codes I think you need to give each thread its own file/unit,
or take other measures to avoid conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

From Gfortran [manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/FLUSH.html):

Beginning with the Fortran 2003 standard, there is a `FLUSH` statement that should be preferred over the `FLUSH` intrinsic.

The `FLUSH` intrinsic and the Fortran 2003 `FLUSH` statement have identical effect: they flush the runtime library's I/O buffer so that the data becomes visible to other processes. This does not guarantee that the data is committed to disk.

On POSIX systems, you can request that all data is transferred to the storage device by calling the fsync function, with the POSIX file descriptor of the I/O unit as argument (retrieved with GNU intrinsic FNUM). The following example shows how:

```
    ! Declare the interface for POSIX fsync function
    interface
      function fsync (fd) bind(c,name="fsync")
      use iso_c_binding, only: c_int
        integer(c_int), value :: fd
        integer(c_int) :: fsync
      end function fsync
    end interface

    ! Variable declaration
    integer :: ret

    ! Opening unit 10
    open (10,file="foo")

    ! ...
    ! Perform I/O on unit 10
    ! ...

    ! Flush and sync
    flush(10)
    ret = fsync(fnum(10))

    ! Handle possible error
    if (ret /= 0) stop "Error calling FSYNC"
```

Answer (score 0):

How about closing the file after every time step (assuming a reasonable amount of time elapses between time steps)?

```
do loop starts
.
.
  !Note: an if statement should wrap the following so that it is
  !only called by one processor.
  open(unit=57,file='inst.dat')
  write(57,*) time
  close(57)
.
.
end do
```

Alternatively if the time between time steps is short, writing the data after blocks of 10, 100, ... iterations may be more efficient.